# How to trace the cause of an error result?

Tags: error-handling, rust

When writing code that uses `Result` type, you may want different behavior for users and developers.

- When writing an application that gracefully handles errors, it's nice to use `Result`.
- During development you may want to "catch" the error to see what line of code creates the error or get a stack-trace the moment the `Err` value is created.

If you make a unique error it's not hard to search for it, but if the error is from the standard library, the error may be very generic.

For example, it's impossible to know which `read` command caused an unexpected end-of-file without manually changing every `file.read()?` to `file.read().unwrap()`.

Is there a convenient way to get a stack-trace from a `Result`?

A  weak but workable solution could be to make a macro for reading, `read_in_release_unwrap_in_debug!(file, data)`... but this feels very awkward.

---

I have a file reader with many `read` calls and one fails. I'm not sure which. At run-time, I want to push the result back to the caller. For debugging, I want the failed read call to stop or somehow let me know its line number.

Answer (score 22):

If you use [`anyhow`](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow) you can get this for free! You enable an environment variable:

```
RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo +nightly run
```

Also enable the `backtrace` crate feature.

Comment: Looks like it's now on stable per the linked PR.

Comment: On Rust `1.65` with `anyhow` `1.0.66` I needed the `backtrace` feature enabled in `Cargo.toml`. ie. `anyhow = { version = "1.0.66", features = ["backtrace"] }`

Comment: `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` `use anyhow::Result` `cargo add anyhow --features backtrace` is that all? I can't see the origin of errors with them though. Is `+nightly` needed still?

Comment: That should do the trick. Nightly isn't required. Not sure why it isn't working for you. Maybe it only works on some platforms?

Answer (score 8):

A result by itself doesn't have any backtrace information, but you can add it to custom error types.

The [error_chain crate](https://crates.io/crates/error-chain) (which is unfortunately [no longer maintained](https://github.com/rust-lang-deprecated/error-chain)) is an example which generates an error type for you, for which you get backtrace generation for free when the `RUST_BACKTRACE` environment variable is set.

You could also use the [backtrace](https://crates.io/crates/backtrace) library directly and do it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

I resolve this requirement with [easy-error](https://crates.io/crates/easy-error) crate, while [error-chain](https://crates.io/crates/error-chain) crate is fine also.

Use [Result](https://docs.rs/easy-error/0.3.1/easy_error/type.Result.html) defined in `easy-error` as return type, then use [context](https://docs.rs/easy-error/0.3.1/easy_error/trait.ResultExt.html#tymethod.context) method to convert other `Result` types.

Most important thing is to pass information to `context` method with line number.

```rust
use easy_error::{Result, ResultExt};
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn test_open() -> Result<()> {
    let mut p = PathBuf::from(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"));
    p.push("resources/test/songs.json");
    File::open(p).context(format!("{}:{}", file!(), line!()))?;
    Ok(())
}
```

To avoid typing `format!("{}:{}", file!(), line!())` all the time, define a macro:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! code_loc {
    () => {
        format!("{}:{}", file!(), line!())
    };
}
```

And finally code will be:

```rust
File::open(p).context(code_loc!())?;
```